Ubuntu 24.04 - Keyboard shortcut to change display resolution
Is it possible to easily change resolution on Ubuntu 24.04 with keyboard shortcuts?
I use some older CAD applications that unfortunately do not scale well to my 5120x2160 res and the small fonts are killing me. Whenever I run those applications, I have to go into Settings >> Display >> Resolution and choose 2560x1080 (then also click on "Keep resolution" etc).
Any shortcuts or quicker solutions are much appreciated.
Thanks


You can use xrandr to change your screen's resolution with a cli. You can launch commands using custom keyboard shortcuts.
This only works on X11. You will need to switch if you are on Wayland.

Open terminal.
Type xrandr. You should see a list of supported resolutions.
Type xrandr | awk '/ connected/ {print $1}'. Note down your monitor's name.
Type xrandr --output <your-display-name> --mode <resolution>. This should change your resolution.
Open Setting -> Keyboard -> View and Customize Shorcuts -> Custom Shortcuts -> Add Shortcut.
Give it a name, paste the previous command and set a custom keystroke combination.

You will have to set two shortcuts to lower and reset your resolution.
Example:
xrandr --output eDP-1-0 --mode 1920x1080

